# Can a hyperlink in MS Word or Excel open in a non-default browser?

Tags: browser, microsoft-office, windows-11, hyperlink

Environment: Windows 11, Office 2021 running on computer, not in "cloud".

My default browser is Firefox and I don't want to change that. But some websites are not compatible with Firefox, so when I make a document in MS Word or Excel, I'd like to set links to those sites to open in Edge.

Is there way to do that?

Preferably without VBA, but VBA okay if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions of Windows 10 and Windows 11 feature a protocol handler "microsoft-edge" that is by default associated to Microsoft Edge.
One can use the insert hyperlink feature in Excel and Word and then for example insert

```
microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com
```

as link which will then open Edge with the specified URL.
This will however trigger a "Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern" dialog when opening the hyperlink

Comment: Easy and works! Thank you. Interesting that Office would issue a security warning on opening an MS browser! Question: Are there other protocol handlers for other browsers if I want to do this with Chrome or others? Is there a list of such handlers somewhere?

Comment: You can view all the protocol handlers registered by Windows by going into Default apps of the Settings app and selecting "Choose by protocol/ link type", it will list all of the protocol handlers and their current app. I don't think/know of any specific to Chrome/Firefox etc. The microsoft-edge one only really exists so Microsoft themselves can force certain stuff (like the start menu search) to open inside Edge. I think the warning appears since office has a very strict whitelist on what it considers safe

Comment: Hmm, at `Settings > Apps > Default apps > Related settings`, I don't have a "Choose by protocol/link type". I do have a "Choose defaults by link type". When I go there, some of the entries have a value suffixed with "Protocol", such as `URL:Acrobat Protocol` and `URL:MailTo Protocol`. But there are two entries for Edge: "Microsoft-Edge" and "Microsoft-Edge-Holographic", and they both have a value of "Microsoft Edge HTML Document", nothing with "Protocol" and nothing with a colon or otherwise looking like a protocol. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are in the correct dialog, I wrote protocol/link type because they changed wording between Windows 10 and 11 and I didn't see your 11 tag. If the protocol for example says URL:Mailto Protocol you would use mailto:yourmail@example.com to call that protocol. Many website use it for example to trigger your default mail client to open

Comment: But there is no protocol indicated for Edge, certainly not the protocol `microsoft-edge:`. So is this the wrong place to be looking for that?

Comment: Also, I've now tried the technique in Excel, and it's not working there. If I preface a hyperlinked cell with "microsoft-edge:" and click on it, it takes me to the URL in Firefox. So inserting the protocol is not causing an error, but is just being ignored. So it's working in Word, but not in Excel. Is there a way to get it to work in Excel?

Comment: I just tested it with Excel 2013 and Excel 365 and it worked in both. I entered the text I wanted into a cell then went to Insert -> Link and the dialog that opens I entered microsoft-edge:https://google.com into the address field. Does your link show microsoft-edge when hovering over it?

Comment: On retesting, I found that if a cell is first linked without the protocol, and then the protocol is inserted (which is what I did before), then the protocol appears in the URL, but it's ignored and the site opens in the default browser. But if the link is created in a fresh cell with the protocol, then the site opens in Edge. So I stand corrected. It does work in Excel, as long as the procedure is done in a cell that has not been previously set to link without the protocol. Apparently, Excel has a memory of how a link worked before and let's that override a change in protocol.

Comment: Going back now to the listing at `Settings > Apps > Default apps > Choose defaults by link type`, do you know why it doesn't show a protocol for Edge and where to find that?

Comment: On my Windows 10 install it shows the microsoft-edge protocol in the settings. But I remember some article about how Microsoft wanted to prevent people to mess with it, so they might have hidden that one protocol from the settings app. If you are really curious about it you could check out the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT hive in regedit. this is where all the protocols are stored internally