# Opening links to websites from the New Outlook in other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-edge

I have just looked at the answer at [Can a hyperlink in MS Word or Excel open in a non-default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/1811793/can-a-hyperlink-in-ms-word-or-excel-open-in-a-non-default-browser).

The accepted answer says:

> Current versions of Windows 10 and Windows 11 feature a protocol handler "microsoft-edge" that is by default associated to Microsoft Edge.
> One can use the insert hyperlink feature in Excel and Word and then for example insert
>
> microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com
> as link which will then open Edge with the specified URL.
> This will however trigger a "Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern" dialog when opening the hyperlink

I have a similar question for the New Outlook. My default browser is Microsoft Edge. Sometimes an incoming mail may have a link to a website, which I will usually open in the default browser. But sometimes there are links to websites which I want to open in Firefox or Chrome. I do not want to keep changing the default browser. So, my question is if there is a feature for the New Outlook using the specific url criteria?

Comment: What criteria do you expect to use to decide what browser is used to open the links? is it a specific url, or time of day, or sender? It would help if you are specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why can’t you copy the URL and navigate to it in the other browser. Without changing the default browser I know of no feature within Windows nor Outlook that would accomplish what you want.

Comment: There are products you can set as your default browser that route the URLs in the links clicked to different browsers. There have been question on this site regarding it. What about your question limits your request only to new Outlook?

Comment: It is not available for the New Outlook using the sender criteria.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Outlook/comments/138ulju/the_latest_try_the_new_outlook_is_hot_garbage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you clear the default for all browsers. So every time you click a hyperlink, it will ask you which browser you want to open.